Maplibre navigationview for turn-by-turn navigation in kotlin
I am using below libraries in Kotlin for creating a simple navigation app:
implementation 'org.maplibre.gl:android-sdk:11.6.1'
implementation 'com.github.maplibre:maplibre-navigation-android:4.0.0'

and this is my whole code about that :
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import org.maplibre.android.MapLibre
import org.maplibre.android.camera.CameraPosition
import org.maplibre.android.geometry.LatLng
import org.maplibre.android.maps.MapLibreMap
import org.maplibre.android.maps.MapView
import org.maplibre.android.plugins.annotation.SymbolManager
import org.maplibre.android.plugins.annotation.SymbolOptions
import org.maplibre.geojson.Point
import org.maplibre.navigation.android.navigation.ui.v5.route.NavigationRoute
import org.maplibre.navigation.android.navigation.v5.models.DirectionsResponse
import org.maplibre.navigation.android.navigation.v5.models.DirectionsRoute
import org.maplibre.navigation.android.navigation.v5.navigation.MapLibreNavigation
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var mapView: MapView
    private lateinit var mapLibreMap: MapLibreMap
    private var pointA: Point? = null
    private var pointB: Point? = null
    private lateinit var navigation: MapLibreNavigation
    private lateinit var symbolManager: SymbolManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        MapLibre.getInstance(this)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        getLocationPermissions()

        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView)
        mapView.getMapAsync { map ->
            mapLibreMap = map
            mapLibreMap.setStyle("https://demotiles.maplibre.org/style.json") { style ->

                symbolManager = SymbolManager(mapView, mapLibreMap, style)
                symbolManager.iconAllowOverlap = true
                symbolManager.textAllowOverlap = true
            }

            mapLibreMap.cameraPosition =
                CameraPosition.Builder().target(LatLng(0.0, 0.0)).zoom(1.0).build()
            mapLibreMap.addOnMapClickListener { point ->
                handleMapClick(point)
                true
            }
        }

        navigation = MapLibreNavigation(this)
    }

    private fun handleMapClick(point: LatLng) {
        val clickedPoint = Point.fromLngLat(point.longitude, point.latitude)

        if (pointA == null) {
            pointA = clickedPoint
            addMarkerToMap(clickedPoint)
        } else if (pointB == null) {
            pointB = clickedPoint
            addMarkerToMap(clickedPoint)

            if (pointA != null && pointB != null) {
                startNavigation(pointA!!, pointB!!)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun addMarkerToMap(point: Point) {
        symbolManager.create(
            SymbolOptions()
                .withLatLng(LatLng(point.latitude(), point.longitude()))
                .withIconImage("default-marker")
                .withIconSize(1.3f)
        )
    }

    private fun startNavigation(origin: Point, destination: Point) {

        NavigationRoute.builder(this)
            .accessToken("removed in here")
            .origin(origin)
            .destination(destination)
            .profile("driving")
            .baseUrl("https://api.mapbox.com/")

            .build()
            .getRoute(object : Callback<DirectionsResponse> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<DirectionsResponse>,
                    response: Response<DirectionsResponse>
                ) {
                    println("ffffffffffffffffffff")
                    println(response.toString())
                    response.body()?.let { responses ->
                        println("sdfkjdflsk")
                        println(responses.toJson())
                        if (responses.routes().isNotEmpty()) {
                            val maplibreResponse = DirectionsResponse.fromJson(responses.toJson())
                            val directionsRoute =
                                DirectionsRoute.fromJson(maplibreResponse.routes().first().toJson())

                            println(directionsRoute.toJson())

                            navigation.startNavigation(directionsRoute)
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<DirectionsResponse>, throwable: Throwable) {
                    println("sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf")
                    println(throwable.message)
                }
            })
    }

}

it works without error and gets to the line navigation.startNavigation(directionsRoute) but nothing happens and also there is no error in logcat
I searched a bit and found that we can use a view like mapview in xml layout file like : com.maplibre.navigation.ui.NavigationView, but in my libraries there is no such thing
what am i missing ?

A few ideas... First, sometimes logcat can be deceptive with the default filters. Have you tried removing the filters? I forget how Mapbox does API key auth, but you might need to set that up as well or else requests will fail. Second, if I recall correctly, this will only start the core navigation service; it won't actually "do" anything else though since you also need to set up the UI.

did you created developer-config.xml ??
